# vscode - expanding folders in version 1.31.0

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just updated my VSCode to the latest version of 1.31.0.
Everything looks fine and there are a bunch of cool new features, but it seems that something has changed in the behavior of expanding and collapsing folders in the explorer pane.
Up until this version, expanding and collpasing of folders was available by simply clicking on the little arrow icon to the left of the folder, like it is in any standard system that displays a tree of folders and files.
Since the latest update, as mentioned here, this seems to be impossible any more and the E&C actions on folder can be done only by double clicking the folder.
Is that a bug or a wanted feature, for some reason?? If that's a wanted feature, I think this is a very wrong decision, because what is the arrow there for, then?? I don't understand why this has changed...
Where can I raise an issue about that? Where can I report that?

Comment: I can't reproduce that. Clicking on the arrow still works here as expected. Maybe try to reinstall VSC.

Comment: It's working fine in my case, by the way, you can easily expand and collapse folder using the right arrow and the left arrow keys, you can go up and down by using the up arrow and the  down arrow keys, and also there is a collapse all button on the top

Answer (score 4):

Actually, this turned out to be a real bug in release 1.31 of VSCode...

When the opening of files is set to "doubleClick" instead of "singleClick" (Settings -> Workbench -> List: Open Mode), the folders can be expanded or collapsed only by double clicking them and the "twistie" arrow does not work any more.
Only when leaving the default settings on "singleClick" (or switching back to it, if changed from default), then the arrows work as they should.

This is a bug because these arrows should always serve their original purpose (which is to expand and collapse folders, of course), regardless to the settings of opening files.

My original report about this can be found here:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/68050

Then, it turned to a fix by one of the developers:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/pull/68088

And after it was accepted and merged, it is designated to be a part of the next minor release (1.31.1).